# Computing argmin of a symbolic function with a lot of variables

Tags: matlab, function, min, symbolic-math

I have a data matrix `X` of size 3065x57 and a column matrix `y` of size 3065x1, and I want to compute the `argmin` the function `sum` defined in the code below.

I tried what is coded below, `fminsearch` and so on, but none work.
Another problem is the fact that I have 57 symbolic variables, so MATLAB computations are very slow.

What can be done to speed up computaions?

```
function [] = argmin(X,y)
w = transpose(sym('w', [1 57]));
sum = 0;
for i=1:3065
    sum = sum + log(1+exp(transpose(w)*transpose(X(i,:)))) -...
        y(i,1)*transpose(w)*transpose(X(i,:));
end
F = matlabFunction(sum);
argmin = fsolve(F,zeros(1,57))
end
```

EDIT: I tried the following:

```
fun = @(w)log(1+exp(transpose([w(1);w(2);w(3);w(4);w(5);w(6);w(7);w(8);w(9);w(10)])*...
    [1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1]))-...
    transpose([w(1);w(2);w(3);w(4);w(5);w(6);w(7);w(8);w(9);w(10)])*...
    [1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1]

x0 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
x = fminsearch(fun,x0)
```

However, I can't do the `for` loop.

Comment: please avoid using default function names as variable names - this is most likely going to bite you sooner or later! `sum()` is already the sum function, `i` is already the imaginary unit.

Comment: First I would suggest to avoid `sym` variables.

Comment: Symbolic variables are very slow in MATLAB, as it is not optimised for it. It uses `eval` under the hood there, shuts down JIT etc. Basically: try to get rid of the symbolic variables, as MATLAB is a numerical tool, which only has symbolic support as a sort-of bonus feature.

Comment: Also please define *none work*. How do they not work? Do you get errors? Wrong results? Does your computer explode? Please be more specific.

Comment: Just for readability, please write `fun` as: `fun = @(w) log(1+exp(w(1:10)*ones(10,1))-w(1:10)*ones(10,1))`, and also `x0 = ones(1,10);` and if you are worry about the shape of `w`, then write: `x = fminsearch(fun,x0(:).')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using things like `fminsearch` and `fmincon`, you don't have to use an anonymous function in the sense you are using it. You can create your own function and make that into an anonymous function.

Also, your minimization variable does not have to be a symbol. As said in the comments this is very slow and unnecessary for your problem.

Code:

```
function sum = argmin_fun(x,y,w)

sum = 0;

for ii = 1:3065
    sum = sum + log(1 + exp(w'*x(ii,:)')) - y(ii)*w'*x(ii,:)';
end

return
```

From your script, you can then call

```
x = randn(3065,57);
y = randn(3065,1);
fun = @(w) argmin_fun(x,y,w);
x0 = ones(57,1);
minimized_vals = fminsearch(fun,x0);
```

A few notes:

Consider using an options variable so you can set up options parameters such as how well you want it to be optimized, max iterations, as well as other parameters, you can set it up like this.

```
opts1 = optimset('Display','iter','MaxIter',100);
minimized_vals = fminsearch(fun,x0,opts1);
```

If you have the optimization toolbox, consider using `fmincon` or one of the other optimizers, `fminsearch` is good for problems with 1-10 variables but becomes much less accurate for large scale problems. With `fmincon` you can also set up boundary constraints for minimum and maximum values. There are workarounds with `fminsearch` but they aren't as easy to implement.

In terms of performance, the error function of `fminsearch` achieved an error value of 9637.23 while `fmincon` achieved an error value of 1945.63 without any constraints added.

```
[minimized_vals,error_val] = fmincon(fun,x0,[],[]);
```

Let me know if I missed anything and I'll ammend my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this very complete answer. Still, I get error related to the agreement of the matrices' dimensions (probably because of the transpositions). The matrix of variables $w$ is a column matrix, so the algorithm needs to be adapted. If you have some time, can you please modify the algorithm?

Comment: I swear the uncertainty principle applies to everything I do, I tested this and it worked yesterday and today it's broken. Editing now.

Comment: Also, you were right, it was the transposes. Linear algebra still eludes me.

Comment: Thank you. Now I get "Exiting: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded - increase MaxFunEvals option. Current function value: 1554.795167". How to continue searching? PS: Try zeros(1,57) instead of ones(1,57), because ones give "Current function value: Inf"

Comment: It was meant to be a minimal verifiable example which obviously isn't going to converge because you're trying to converge random numbers. As for options, you're best off looking through the various options you can set for optimizers, there's simply too many to list here. One of those is maximum function evaluations, it's simply the number of times it is allowed to call your function. Those things are set up so that it doesn't try and run forever trying to optimize. Try and run it with your problem with it and see how it performs. From there try and tune it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want remove the loop, you can use matrix operations:

```
 a = transpose(w)*transpose(X);
```

`a` is a vector with size of 1 x 3065 (as `w'` is 1 x 57 and `X'` is 57 x 3065).
Now you can do the second operation like the following:

```
b = transpose(y).*a
```

So, `sum` would be:

```
totalSum =  sum(log(1+exp(a)) - b);
```

You should consider that as the `sum` is a function in Matlab, it would be better change the name of `sum` variable`to`sum`.

In sum, we can remove the loop and replace the loop with the followings:

```
a = transpose(w)*transpose(X); % w: 57 x 1, X:3065 x 57
b = b = transpose(y).*a; % y: 3065 x 1, a: 1 x 3065
totalSum =  sum(log(1+exp(a)) - b);
```

It could be so faster than which you write for the first solution.